# Reference request: Queueing and reliability theory from a stochastic point of view

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, queueing-theory

I am an analyst and looking for good references on the topic "Queueing and reliability theory" but from a probabilistic perspective. Ideally, I would like to find a monograph on this topic, including chapters on continuous-time Markov chains, and applications to standard examples from queues like the M/M/1-Queue. However, if you know some good other references, then they are appreciated as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used heavily the book by V. Kalashnikov, Mathematical Methods in Queuing Theory as well as the book by Asmussen, Applied Probability and Queues.

The two books by Bremaud on Markov chains and Queuing were also helpful to me.